# How to read multiple condition Python Arduino Uno

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I have a question.
I am currently working on the python-Arduino Uno project.

so here we go.
I wanna send the value from python 1 to Arduino
and get the other value from python 2.
so actually I want to make the Arduino Uno that can read 2 conditions
then it will do stuff...

code python 1

```
i = results[1]
    i *= 100
    if i >= 75:
        print('Recognised as Me!')
        arduino.write(str.encode('1'))
    else:
        print('not matches')
        arduino.write(str.encode('0'))
```

code python 2

```
c = results[0]
    c *= 100
    d = results[2]
    d *= 100
    e = results[1]
    e *= 100
    for a in top_k:
        if a == 0 and c >= 50:
            arduino.write(str.encode('a'))
        if a == 1 and e > 50:
            arduino.write(str.encode('h'))
        if a == 2 and d >= 50:
            arduino.write(str.encode('s'))
```

Arduino code

```
int pin = 13;
char getValue;
void setup()
{

  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{



 if(Serial.available() > 0)
  getValue = Serial.read();
  Serial.print(getValue);
  if (getValue == '1' && getValue == 'h' ) { //its not works for me. 
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
  }

  else if (getValue == '0'){
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
    delay(1000); 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only reading the value once, then comparing that same value twice. You need to read the value **again** using `Serial.read()` if you want to compare a second value. A simple example of this:

```java
  value1 = Serial.read();
  Serial.print(value1);

  value2 = Serial.read();
  Serial.print(value2);

  if (value1 == '1' && value2 == 'h' ) { 
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
  }
```

Comment: sorry, sir, it works now. but why the response is so slow? I mean. the Arduino needs 10 s just to give the output

Comment: @whatever Hm... I'm not sure. I would recommend putting some more `Serial.println` in various places to determine where the code is getting caught up.